# JQuery Dropdown behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

really new to JQuery.. like 2 hours new. Began to write a drop down menu for a login box like this:
HTML:

```
<button id="loginButton">Login</button>
```

When you hover over that, this JQuery runs:

```
$('#loginButton').live('hover', function() {
    login_drop();   
});

function login_drop(){
$('#loginBox').fadeIn();

}

$('#loginButton').live('hover', function() {
    login_away();

});

function login_away(){
$('#loginBox').fadeOut();
}
```

And then this HTML DIV appears directly under the button:

```
<div id="loginBox">                
<label for="email_B">Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="email_B" id="email_B" />
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password_B" name="password_B" id="password_B" />
<input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign in" />
<label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Remember me</label>
<span><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
</div>
```

and the CSS on that DIV is this:

```
#loginBox {
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    right:100px;
    display:none;
 z-index:1;
}
```

This all works, but the behavior of it stinks. How do I make it so you can hover over the button put your mouse in the newly appeared DIV and the div won't fade away until your mouse leaves the div?

Sorry if my coding stinks.
Thanks a bunch guys!

--------------------------------EDITS AKA the ANSWERS--------------------
So for all of you reading this down the line. There are so many ways of making this work depending on how you want the user to interact with it.

Here is way 1...This way the login box fades out when your mouse leaves the login button. This is a quick way fo making it work. This answer is thanks to elclanrs besure to Up 1 his answer below if you like this.

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('#loginButton').mouseenter(function(){ $('#loginBox').fadeIn(); }); 
$('#login').mouseout(function(){ $('#loginBox').fadeOut(); }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="loginBox">                
<label for="email_B">Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="email_B" id="email_B" />
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password_B" name="password_B" id="password_B" />
<input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign in" />
<label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Remember me</label>
<span><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#loginBox {
position:absolute;
top:70px;
right:100px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
display:none;
z-index:99;
background:url(../images/162.png);
}
```

WAY 2 is adding is a cancel button like Jared Farrish did here:
http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/4/
if you like his answer, be sure to vot him up below!!

and WAY 3 is what I'm attempting now and should be the most user friendly and flashy. I'll post back once I get it to work correctly!

Comment: JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/

Comment: Mouseovers on a button element to show content are not a great UI design. I would say your design scheme is flawed due to this, and you should just show the form on click or some other recognizable behavior.

Comment: I have the id on an li element on a top menu. I just threw it on a button to make it easier for you guys to read.

Comment: You don't need to edit the answers into your question (in fact, you should not do this). If you have a better answer than the others, just answer your own question instead of editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

(Subsequent EDIT: added a timeout to hide after only a mouseover on the show login element, plus some other updates.)

While I still think using `mouseenter` and `mouseout` to handle a login form is not the right way to go from a usability perspective, below is code that demonstrates what Jim Jeffers is describing and attempts to handle some of the pitfalls of the approach:

```
var setuplogindisplay = function(){
    var $loginbox = $('#loginBox'),
        $loginshow = $('#loginShow'),
        $logincontainer = $('#loginContainer'),
        $cancellogin = $('#cancelLogin'),
        keeptimeout,
        closetimeout;

    var keepDisplay = function(){
        clearAllTimeouts();
        keeptimeout = setTimeout(loginHide, 2000);
    };

    var loginDisplay = function(){
        clearAllTimeouts();
        if ($loginbox.is(':hidden')) {
            $loginbox.fadeIn();
        }
    };

    var loginHide = function(){
        clearAllTimeouts();
        if ($loginbox.is(':visible')) {
            if (!$(this).is('#cancelLogin')) {
                closetimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    $loginbox.fadeOut();
                }, 1500);
            } else {
                $loginbox.fadeOut();
            }
        }
    };

    function clearAllTimeouts() {
        if (keeptimeout) {
            clearTimeout(keeptimeout);
        }
        if (closetimeout) {
            clearTimeout(closetimeout);
        }
    }

    $loginshow.mouseover(loginDisplay);
    $loginshow.mouseout(keepDisplay);
    $logincontainer
        .mouseout(loginHide)
        .children()
            .mouseover(loginDisplay)
            .mouseout(keepDisplay);
    $cancellogin.click(loginHide);
};

$(document).ready(setuplogindisplay);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/19/

Note, you have to make concessions to handle the fact `mouseout`s will fire when you mouse over elements within the `#logincontrol` element. I handle this by having them `loginDisplay()` on `mouseenter` event (it will work on `mouseout`, but it makes more logical sense on `mouseenter`).

---

I would keep in mind usability of the form when trying to access it and try not to get too clever or over-engineer the user experience. Consider:

```
<input type="button" id="cancelLogin" value="Cancel" />
```

Use this to close/hide the form, not an action on another element. If you put the close form action on an event like `mouseout`, you're going to aggravate your users when they move the mouse accidentally or intentionally out of the way, only to find the login form was closed when they did so. The form, IMO, should have the control which fires the event to hide it according to the user's choice.

```
<span id="loginButton">Show Login</span>
<div id="loginBox">                
    <label for="email_B">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_B" id="email_B" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password_B" name="password_B" id="password_B" />
    <input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign in" />
    <input type="button" id="cancelLogin" value="Cancel" />
    <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Remember me</label>
    <span><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $loginbox = $('#loginBox'),
        $button = $('#loginButton'),
        $cancellogin = $('#cancelLogin');

    var loginDisplay = function(){
        $loginbox.fadeIn();
    };

    var loginHide = function(){
        $loginbox.fadeOut();
    };

    $button.click(loginDisplay);
    $cancellogin.click(loginHide);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/4/

Comment: I like this alot. The cancel button makes sense.

Comment: If I were having to interact with [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/8/) to access my account on a site, I'd be annoyed.

Comment: LOL yeah, I'm going to add the cancelLogin ID to an "X" at the top right.

Comment: When I was looking at it, I realized I had not accounted for the fact that the `mouseout` will be fired once you hover over an element *within* the element with the `mouseout` event. So in other words, as soon as you mouse over one of the elements in the `#loginBox` element, the `mouseout` fires. See: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/10/ for how I handled this and incorporated a `setTimeout` to adjust the `loginHide()` function so it's not quite so problematic.

Comment: JARED!!! You are the freaken man! I was literally just combining Jim and Yours' answer, but I'm very slow at JQuery, you did exactly what i was trying to do in 15 minutes. Thanks a bunch! I don;t have enough reputation to vote your comments up, going to ask my friend who uses this site alot to do it. Thanks so much man!!!

Comment: @Silas - See my latest edit. One of the side effects of answering questions with real code is that it can be difficult to quickly spot problems in real time as you're providing it. I've fixed several little flaws with the timeout and whatnot; I believe this code should work, but if it doesn't, just let me know.

Comment: If fact, you're going to want to put a timeout on the menu event that shows the display as well, so it doesn't just sit there open. I'm trying to figure out how to best implement that as well.

Comment: @Silas - See my edit for the `keeptimeout` functionality, plus some additional updates/changes.

Comment: @Silas - Some additional updates involving the `X` you were talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/20/

Answer (score 3):

Ah this is a great one to do yourself. Here's how to do it. First off, live might be overkill for what you need to do. In your case you can use a standard hover event handler in jQuery:

```
$('#loginButton').hover(function() {
  $('#loginBox').fadeIn();
}), function(){
  $('#loginBox').fadeOut();
});
```

The real trick here is that you will trigger the mouse out effect as soon as your mouse moves off the button. This will make the menu disappear when the mouse enters the login box!

So what you actually want to do is handle the hover effect on a containing element. Make sure your #loginButton and #loginBox are contained in a parent element like so:

```
<div id="loginControl">
   <button id="loginButton">Login</button> 
   <div id="loginBox">...</div>
</div>
```

Then attach the event to the loginButton's parent:

```
$('#loginButton').parent().hover(function() { ... }), function(){ ... });
```

Also, if you are using absolute positioning on #loginBox you'll want to also make sure you use position: relative on it's parent (#loginControl in my example):

```
#loginControl{ position: relative; }
```

Let me know if you have any trouble.

**Getting More Advanced:**

If you want to take this a step further you can try out implementing a simple timeout. I learned early on that it's bad for usability to have a dropdown menu that disappears when I accidentally moved my mouse off the dropdown. To fix this I add a simple delay that prevents the dropdown from hiding if the user's mouse returns to the dropdown within a very short period of time (say 250 to 350ms). I have this as a gist on github in case you want to try it out later: https://gist.github.com/71548

Comment: This a great way of doing it. I understand it and the delay is a great idea. I didn't know you could add a delay. Trying this now. Going to see how user friendly I can make this.

Comment: If you have the `#loginControl` element already, why not use it instead of finding the parent of `#loginButton`?

Comment: If I had enough reputation, I'd vote you up. I just may make you the answer shortly though! thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Silas - This would be an implementation of the approach Jim is talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/10/ Note the use of `clearTimeout()` and the fact that I put the `loginDisplay` handler on each of the `.children()` of `#loginControl` to prevent the `mouseout`s that fire when you move the mouse around the form.

Comment: JARED!!! You are the freaken man! I was literally just combining Jim and Yours' answer, but I'm very slow at JQuery, you did exactly what i was trying to do in 15 minutes. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Silas - I left a bit of extraneous code in that fiddle, here is a fiddle without it: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/11/

Comment: @JaredFarrish correct you could use #loginControl directly. I was just showing how you could easily traverse in jQuery and thought it'd be easier to follow if I referenced the elements silas was already using as much as possible rather than the new one I added in my example.

Comment: I seriously wish I could give Jared and Jim both the answers. Damn this site and it's limitations. Ya'll solved my problem well and efficiently! Can;t thank you enough. My boy is gunna vote you guys up because my account lon't let me do anything.

Comment: Well... It could also encourage bad or inefficient practices. What's appropriate is to select the correct element initially, not later; otherwise, it could lead to unexpected bugs (like if the `#loginButton` was wrapped in another element later on in the design/development). Explain why you're doing it that way if you have to, but it's my opinion to demonstrate appropriate code unless otherwise specified and noted.

Comment: @JaredFarrish to be fair, both approaches have their advantages. Neither is incorrect but one could be preferred by a given programmer for a given situation. In most cases like this one, I personally prefer to reference the parent() and embed sub navigations as shown in my example gist.

Comment: I am being fair; without seeing a full code example in which the context for doing it that way (for instance, if you were accessing a cached jQuery object), I don't know it is expressive of what you're suggesting. By itself, without a cached element or anything else, I think it's problematic. It's not worth arguing over either, so if you believe there's not a way to improve the example code, I can live that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I would recommend looking into a jquery plugin like hoverintent. It does most of the work for you.

And, on a related note, .live() is being deprecated in jquery as of v1.8. you should instead use .on().

Comment: I'm sorry. I was reading through stuff and couldn't get the mouseenter to work, but I got the live function to work. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Plus you don't need `live()` which by the way is deprecated in favor on `on()`. You also don't need those functions for a simple `fadeIn()/fadeOut()`:

```
$('#loginButton').mouseenter(function(){ $('#loginBox').fadeIn(); });
$('#loginBox').mouseout(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(); });
```

Comment: AWESOME! Yeah i saw the mouseenter and out on the JQuery website, I just didn't understand how to use it! thanks a bunchg man!

Comment: $(function(){


$('#loginButton').mouseenter(function(){ $('#loginBox').fadeIn(); }); 
$('#loginBox').mouseout(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(); }); 

}); Using it like this.. is that ok?

Comment: What do you mean "like this". You mean all in one line?

Comment: I put this $(function(){ }); around it. It works great, thanks man!

Comment: @Silas - It's a poor choice to show/hide a login form with mouse enter and out events. Compare: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/8/ to http://jsfiddle.net/j4Sj5/9/ and I think you'll see that the mouse events don't exactly handle the process of completing the login very well.